# Convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{\cos(n + \frac{1}{n^2})}{n \cdot \ln(n^2 + 1)}$ Is my idea correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Convergence:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\cos \left(n + \frac{1}{n^2} \right)}{n \cdot \ln \left( n^2 + 1 \right)}$$

Edit (I tried to follow the idea written by @Daniel Fischer):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(n + \frac{1}{n^2})}{n\cdot ln(n^2 + 1)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(n)}{n \cdot ln(n^2 + 1)} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(n + \frac{1}{n^2}) - cos(n)}{n \cdot ln(n^2 + 1)}$$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(n)}{n \cdot ln(n^2 + 1)}$ is convergent because of Dirichlet test and [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(n + \frac{1}{n^2}) - cos(n)}{n \cdot ln(n^2 + 1)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{-2 \left(sin \left( \frac{2n+\frac{1}{n^2}}{2} \right) \cdot sin \left( \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{2} \right) \right)}{n \cdot ln \left(n^2 + 1 \right)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{-2 \left(sin \left( n+\frac{1}{2n^2} \right) \cdot sin \left( \frac{1}{2n^2} \right) \right)}{n \cdot ln \left(n^2 + 1 \right)}$

Then:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{-2 \left(sin \left( n+\frac{1}{2n^2} \right) \cdot sin \left( \frac{1}{2n^2} \right) \right)}{n \cdot ln \left(n^2 + 1 \right)} \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| 2 \cdot \frac{ \frac{1}{2n^2} }{n \cdot ln \left(n^2 + 1 \right)} \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{ 1 }{n^3 \cdot ln \left(n^2 + 1 \right)} \right| $$

For $n \geq 3$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{ 1 }{n^3 \cdot ln \left(n^2 + 1 \right)} \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{n^2} \right|$$

Therefore we know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(n + \frac{1}{n^2}) - cos(n)}{n \cdot ln(n^2 + 1)}$ it is also convergent. Is that correct?

Comment: Write $$\cos\biggl(n + \frac{1}{n^2}\biggr) = \cos n + \biggl(\cos \biggl(n + \frac{1}{n^2}\biggr) - \cos n\biggr)\,.$$

Comment: @Daniel Fischel could you tell me if I did it correct? I tried to use your hint.

Comment: I see now (overlooked it yesterday) that you start your summation at $n = 0$, but the term for $n = 0$ is undefined. Start the summation at $n = 1$ (or later). Apart from that, everything is correct. At the end, the $n \geq 3$ is a little odd (I guess it comes from $\ln n \geqslant 1$ for $n \geqslant 3$, but here we could use $\ln (n^2+1) > 1$ for $n \geqslant 2$). Also that you use $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for the comparison rather than $\frac{1}{n^3}$ is a little odd. I have two ideas why you did that, a) you prefer to use a more "famous" series for comparison,

Comment: or b) you prefer to use a weaker result when that suffices. Both are valid and often useful strategies, but if not made explicit can lead to the question "Why did the author not use [whatever] here?". Depending on the background, it can be simpler/preferable to use the mean value theorem to estimate the difference of the cosines rather than the addition theorem plus $\lvert \sin x\rvert \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$ as you did. It's less to type at least. But the addition theorem may be available before differentiation, so that's (possibly) a more elementary way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from the remark made in the comments,
$$\cos\biggl(n + \frac{1}{n^2}\biggr) = \cos n + \biggl(\cos \biggl(n + \frac{1}{n^2}\biggr) - \cos n\biggr).$$
The second term on the right decays like $1/n^2$, since cosine is Lipschitz continuous (prove this using the cosine sum identity). The partial sums of the first term on the right are uniformly bounded; to see this, it is convenient to remember cosine is the real part of the complex exponential,
$$ \cos n =  \operatorname{Re} e^{in}. $$
Thus the partial sum of cosine is just the real part of a nice geometric series,
$$ \sum_{n = 0}^m \cos n = \operatorname{Re} \sum_{n = 0}^m e^{in} = \operatorname{Re} \frac{1 - e^{i(m + 1)}}{1 - e^i}. $$
The right hand side has uniformly bounded modulus in $m$, so we are done.

Comment: I like that solution. Could you check mine? I will mark your answer as the correct one if everyting is ok.

Comment: @mymathc yes your solution is essentially equivalent to mine, you implicitly proved Lipschitz continuity of cosine in your solution.

Comment: Thank you, finally, that makes me happy :D